# What conditional logic can be used for subclassed booleans in Swift?

Tags: swift, boolean, uitextfield

I'm subclassing a UITextfield in order to create a overlay button to the right which will toggle the isSecureTextEntry boolean.  Typically when creating IBActions in storyboard the boolean is determined based on the sender which I'd implement in Objective-C code like this:

```
-(IBAction)showPasswordTapped:(UIButton *)sender{
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
   self.passwordField.secureTextEntry = !sender.selected;
}
```

However, now that I'm subclassing I was thinking of using an if else statement but the logic looked as if it would just set the boolean back to true.  What would be the appropriate conditional statement if I don't have access to sender?

Here is my subclass in Swift:

```
class SecurePasswordUITextField : UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.isSecureTextEntry = true
        var overlayButton = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        overlayButton.titleLabel = "Show"
        overlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSecureCharacters), for: .touchUpInside)
        overlayButton = CGRect.init(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: 28, height: 28)
        self.rightView = overlayButton
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
    func showSecureCharacters(){
        if self.isSecureTextEntry {
            self.isSecureTextEntry = false
        } else {
            self.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }
        if !self.isSecureTextEntry{
            self.isSecureTextEntry = true
        } else {
            self.isSecureTextEntry = false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's Objective-C code, not Swift. And can you clarify your question? What `if/else` are you referring to?

Comment: @rmaddy Sure, I've edited the question.  I apologize for the initial code being in Objective-C as I'm working with a project that has both.

Comment: So your question seems to be "how to access 'sender' in a button selector in Swift". You really should rewrite your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the sender

```
overlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSecureCharacters(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

//

```
@objc func showSecureCharacters(_ sender:UIButton){ --- }
```

Also this is sufficient

```
self.isSecureTextEntry = !self.isSecureTextEntry
```